# The requirement for authentication of event subscribers in ServiceStack

Tags: servicestack

My client-server application uses ServerEventsFeature to send commands to the client from the server. 
In the client I use ServerEventsClient and its Start method to subscribe to events, but first I'm sending the authentication request to a server using ServerEventsClient.ServiceClient and its Send method.

My client also needs to constantly connect to the server if the connection was broken. 
For this I use OnException Action property of my ServerEventsClient, and when the connection breaks, I call the Stop method in the cycle and try again to send the authentication request until the server responds.

It all works well, but if I restart the server, before the client has time to send the authentication request, I see on the server subscribe events (OnConnect, OnSubscribe, and so on), and when checking the properties of a subscription, I get strange values like IsAuthenticated: False, UserId: -2. 
Then comes the authentication request, and again there are expected subscribe events, and this time, the property values are already expected like IsAuthenticated: True, UserId: 46. 
This SessionId in the first case differs from the value before it is disconnected, but does not match the value after authentication. 
In the OnConnect event handler I tried to check the IsAuthenticated property and call the Unsubscribe method of the object IEventSubscription, but after that still occurs OnSubscribe event. 
I have 2 questions:

Q1: It is obviously that ServerEventsClient automatically tries to reconnect after a breakup. 
In this case, probably the Stop method not triggered because the client cannot perform an unsubscribe request, because the server is not available.
How then to stop this process when unavailable the server?

Q2: Can I prevent an event subscription is not authorized clients?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Server Events Clients send heartbeats to determine when to automatically try reconnect after it detects a broken connection. You can stop heartbeats by removing the `heartbeatUrl` returned to the client, e.g:

```
Plugins.Add(new ServerEventsFeature {
    OnConnect = (sub, clientInfo) => clientInfo.Remove("heartbeatUrl")
});
```

You can limit Server Events to only allow Authenticated Users with:

```
Plugins.Add(new ServerEventsFeature {
    LimitToAuthenticatedUsers = true,
});
```